# How to creat a matrix(array)of size 10 and set all value is 0. With clash(i,j)=0

Tags: python, matrix

```
N = 10
# input the number of columns
M = 10
# initializing the matrix
res = [ [ i*j for i in range(N) ] for j in range(M) ]
clash(i,j)=0
# printing in multiple lines
print("Multiline representation")
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(M):
          #matrix.append(["0"]*100)
      print(res[i][j] ,end =" ")
   print("")
```

There exist an error shows can't assign to function call on clash
(i,j)=0.Thus, i really need help!

Comment: `clash(i,j)=0`  is not valid Python syntax and the error tells you exactly why. What exactly is the confusion?

Comment: After the matrix part, i need to record three pieces of information:
(1) Request1 (2) Request2 (3) Clash value

then need to set:

clash(Request1,Request2)=clash value
clash(Requet2,Request1)=clash value.         Thus i need create a matrix with clash(i,j)=0. But i don't know how to correct it.

Comment: What is `clash`? Where is it defined?

Comment: this is my data.   1   2 D = 238, 1 171 L >   8. The clash is the number of 238 and 8. 1,2 means i.j

Comment: Possibly you mean to do `clash[i][j] = 0`?

Comment: I will try it! thank you

Answer (score -1):

I believe numpy is much more suited for this

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((i,j))
```

EDIT:
To set values use:

```
array[y][x] = value
```

Comment: yes, it is more easier. But After the matrix part, i need to read a data and  record three pieces of information: (1) Request1 (2) Request2 (3) Clash value then need to set: clash(Request1,Request2)=clash value clash(Requet2,Request1)=clash value. Thus i need create a matrix with clash(i,j)=0. But i don't know how to correct it. –

Comment: But this would do that, you would have to use: array[y][x] = clash value

Comment: i will try it !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe by creating list? 
`matrix = [[0] * 10] * 10`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsCkB.png)

Comment: Be careful when using the `*` operator. Especially when you are generating arrays of values. This is because the created `matrix` variable will be a `list` of references to the same `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` list, so modifying `matrix[0]` will mean the remaining rows will also change, unless you're just replacing the entire list.